# pandas , add a constant to column based on condition on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame :

```
A B 
1 2
4 3 
5 9
6 7
9 7
```

I want to check if values in column A are divisible by 2 (check odd even) if they are divisible by two then I want to add 18 to the value in Column B

So far I have been able to check if value in column A is divisible by 2 and extract it.

```
df = df[df['A'] % 2 == 0]
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if any post answered your question as expected

Answer (score 5):

`df['A']%2==0` will return boolean series where `A` is divisible by 2 and then corresponding values of `B` would be updated

```
df.loc[df['A']%2==0, 'B'] = df['B'] + 18
df

    A   B
0   1   2
1   4   21
2   5   9
3   6   25
4   9   7
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['A'] % 2 == 0, 'B'] += 18` Short syntax

Comment: Thanks for the help and answer

Comment: @ScottBoston It would shorten the syntax but `df['A']%2==0` part would be calculated again and so would be more costly and output remains same

Comment: @ggaurav I am not sure, I agree with your statement here.  I am finding with %timeit the statement I offered is faster.

Comment: @ggaurav Try this dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(0,1000, 10000000),
                   'B':np.random.randint(0,10, 10000000)})`

Comment: For me, it is the otherway around. `%%timeit
df.loc[df['A'] % 2 == 0, 'B'] += 18` `377 ms ± 70.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` . Whereas `%%timeit
df.loc[df['A']%2==0, 'B'] = df['B'] + 18` -> `360 ms ± 21.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: I was timing the dataframe in question and the timings were similar for both. I think any of them can be used, maybe based on readability.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try:

```
df['B']=np.where(df['A'] % 2 == 0,df.B.add(18),df.B)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and answer